# convertion of decimal number to any other base (2<=base<=36) in python

Tags: python

Is there any inbuilt function to convert decimal number to any other base..
please help me to convert a given number to the desired base which is between 2 and 36.

Comment: use builtin function int
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Comment: if am using int('-jj',20) am getting 399. which is true!! But i want it in reverse that is I want to convert 399 to the equivalent number in base 20